# Phonegap doesn't work because of Java

Tags: java, android, cordova

I have tried to install Phonegap for Android, and although I have solved many issues there is one I cannot resolve. I have set JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME as:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
C:\Development\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.8.3.v201301120609
```

And this is my path:

```
C:\Users\fylux\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12;C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Development\adt-bundle\sdk\tools;C:\Development\sdk\tools;;%JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\;%ANT_HOME%\bin;
```

Well, you can see the error in the picture when I write `cordova build`.

[image]

Greetings and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Now I have installed JDK 1.8 so I fixed the first problem, but now it looks like this:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a JDK not a JRE. Go get one [on the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), install it (for example [the JDK 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)).

It will then locate the `javac` executable, and you'll be good to go.

If it does not work just after, close your console window and rerun, or set pass with set `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7`

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have installed JDK and it installed also jre8. Well. now I have jdk1.8.0_11 and I have set JAVA_HOME as C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11. But now, the error is: Class not found javac1.8

Comment: Don't forget to add `\bin` after `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk7` in your PATH environment variable. Apparently `javac` needs this.

Comment: I have got this in my PATH: %JAVA_HOME%\bin\;%JAVA_HOME%\lib\

Comment: I have also installed jdk1.7.0_67 but I get the same problem. It is rare that it is called jdk1.7.0_67, instead of jkd7.

Comment: If your initial setup does not work, then most probably the setup is messed up and you would waste time in debugging the situation. One option is to start a fresh installation. I would suggest that do the following. Locate the **.cordova** folder most likely will be in your `c:\development\adritah` folder. Delete the **.cordova** folder. Then delete the **project** directory in the workspace. Install ANT, JDK. Set the environment PATH, ANDROID_SDK, JAVA_HOME,ANT_HOME variable. Finally run all the cordova commands again to create the build. This is what workded for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but inside C:\Development\adritah I have: hooks, platforms, plugins, www and config.xml. I don't know where is .cordova. And, do I have to instal ANT and JDK again? Do I have to unistall and install?. And about the enviroment PATH, do I have to delete the current JAVA_HOME and create a new one or it doesn't matter. And something important, I didn't intall Ant directly, It was downloaded with the Android SDK and is in eclipse->plugins. And finally, I don't have a variable called ANDROID_SDK. Greetings and thanks.